# Create a valid JSON with arrays from Database with Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, mariadb, simplejson

I'm trying to get a JSON File like this using Python and grab data from a MariaDB on a Linux System. How can I achieve this?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "city": "A",
      "age": "21"
    },
    {
      "city": "B",
      "age": "45"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how my Python file looks:

```
import csv
import datetime
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import simplejson
import os

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user', password='passwd', database='db1')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name,age FROM persons ORDER BY name ASC")

data = cursor.fetchall()
names_as_dict = []

for row in data:
 name_as_dict = {
           'name' : row[0],
           'age' : row[1]
 }
 names_as_dict.append(name_as_dict)

with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
    simplejson.dump(names_as_dict, f)
```

The output of this file:

```
[
  {
    "city": "A",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "city": "B",
    "age": "45"
  },
...
]
```

Comment: `{'data':name_as_dict}`?

Comment: You mean like this? names_as_dict = [] names2_as_dict = {"data": names_as_dict} If yes, this is not working: Traceback (most recent call last): File "script_db.py", line 22, in <module> names2_as_dict.append(name_as_dict) AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: No, as in that's what you pass to `json.dump`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, this is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with additional dictionary

```
result = {'data': [{'name' : row[0],'age' : row[1]} for row in data]}
```

Comment: You mean like this?
`names_as_dict = []
names2_as_dict = {"data": names_as_dict}
`
If yes, this is not working:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_db.py", line 22, in <module>
    names2_as_dict.append(name_as_dict)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`